# Lucky, she thought, that he was not aware of it

Tags: conversational-deletion

> Lucky, she thought, that he was not aware of it.

This sentence is from a Korean grammar text that I read in my old school days. 
It’s translation - 그가 그것을 눈치채지 못한 것은 다행이라고 그녀는 생각했다 - is just like this pattern: *[She] [thought] [him / kind and generous]* ([OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/think_1)). 
Is it really “[She] [thought] [that he was not aware of it / lucky]” structure? 
Or “It was lucky, she thought, that he was not aware of it” something?

Comment: Just for fun, I ran your Korean text through Google Translate, which gave me this: "She said that he was glad I did not notice it" ... and Babylon, which gave me this: "He may not have noticed it is fortunate, she thought." So much for machine translation. :)

Comment: @StoneyB Translations, through machine-translators, between English and Korean don’t make any sense at all. So in Korean question-answer websites for learning English, ‘No Machine-Translators Please! (번역기 사절)’ is the questioners’ hackneyed title. Because the construction order is quite different and we attach suffixes to nouns, adjectives, adverbs, almost all the words.

Comment: @StoneyB So the order of words are quite free, because their meanings are clear regardless of their positions. The others are minor comparing to this difference that blocks the translators’ intelligence. When I sometimes hear some foreigners say by my language on TV show, it’s a mystery how they can say that fluently. Men are superior than machines, that’s what.

Comment: It is the great linguistic mystery: how does anybody learn such a complicated program? Yet everybody does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are  right: *Lucky* is indeed a part of the ‘object’ of the displaced head clause *she thought*.

A *paraphrase* might adopt the *SUBJ THINK OBJ OBJ-COMPL* construction, as your grammar text suggests:

> She thought it lucky that he was not aware of it.

—but that doesn't begin to unfold the complexities of this sentence. To my mind you would do better to think of it this way:

1. The sentence is an indirect report of a direct quote, whose present-tense verb has been backshifted to agree with past-tense *thought*.

   > “Lucky,” she thought, “that he **is** not aware of it.”
2. *She thought* has been displaced from its canonical position at the head of the sentence

   > She thought, “Lucky that he is not aware of it.”

   This is a standard literary convention: it parenthesizes the putative ‘main clause’ (here *she thought*) and focuses what comes before it.
3. *Lucky* here represents *It is lucky*, abbreviated through [*conversational deletion*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/58445/24489), which permits ‘old information’ at the head of the sentence to be omitted, leaving ‘new information’ as the focus.

   > She thought “<s>It is</s> lucky that he is not aware of it.”
4. And the entire original direct-speech clause is itself an *it* cleft, representing an underlying canonical clause

   > That he is unaware of it [is] lucky.

   The *it* cleft construction is, again, a device for focusing the element which follows the dummy subject and copula.

Note that all of these transformations except that which converts direct to indirect speech have the same goal: putting (or preserving) the focus on *lucky*.